# How can I check what happens when I submit a form in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.4, form-for

My `lists_controller.rb` provides `@list` and `@lists` from the duplicate method

```
  def duplicate
    @lists = List.includes(:list_fields, :user, :list_parts)
    @list = List.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

And I have got a form in my duplicate.html.erb file.

```
<%= form_for( @list, :html => { :class => "formtastic normal", :id => "generator_form" }) do |f| -%>
        <fieldset>
          <ol>
            <li>
              <%= label_tag :list_source, "Available lists" %>
              <%= select "list", "original_id", @lists.sort{|a,b| a.title <=> b.title}.collect{|p| [p.title[0,50]+"...", p.id] }, { :include_blank => "Please select a list" } %>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </fieldset>
        <p><%= f.submit "Duplicate" -%></p>
<% end -%>
```

The select helper gives me a drop down menu from which I can select a list. When I click submit, a new list is created (from an existing one) and saved in my database but I don't really know what happens behind the scene when I submit (click "Duplicate"). How can I check that ?

Comment: You can read logs. You can debug. Please read: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Rails logger. In development environment it prints out information in terminal when server is running

Also it writes logs in file. By default destination is `log/<environment>.log`

So you can use `tail` command. For example, to read output in real time in production

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

Also you can specify logging level and setup log message format

And you can manually call logger in your code like this

```
Rails.logger.info 'your message'
```

In logs you will see requested action and controllers, parameters from your form, SQL-queries, what was rendered or where redirected etc.

Please read more in [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I didn't know the existence of logger, very helpful indeed. One question : when you try to debug, do you clear the development.log file everytime you want to see something ?? Otherwise the file gets very long and you have to scroll to the bottom.

Comment: @Maxime you can use commands `tail`, `grep` etc. in terminal. Also it is good practice to use logrotate tool